# Como verificar se o usuário digitou algum caracter especial no EditText?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-eclipse

Como eu consigo verificar se o usuário digitou algum caracter especial (*, /, +, &, etc.) sem ser pelo `if(srt.contains("@") || srt.contains("!") || ...` ?

Há alguma maneira mais prática?

E se ele digitou, o que faço para "travar" essa digitação?

Comment: Caractere especial você se refere aos que não são letras e números ou tem uma lista específica?

Answer (score 1):

Parecido com a resposta do William, porém filtrando apenas para letras ou números.

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
            Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(source.charAt(i))) {
                return "";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};
seuEditTxt.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```
if ("teste".indexOf("$") >= 0)   
   // Tem $  
else  
   // Não tem $
```

Pode colocar filtro também, assim:

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter()
{
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
    {
        if (source.toString().contains("@"))
            return "";
        else
            return null; // Accept original replacement.
    }    
};

editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
```